# Duplicate logging in log4J2 with custom levels

Tags: java, log4j2

I am facing problem of log message being added to multiple appenders even after providing correct level.
Please find following Log4 configuraiton and java sample code.
Log4J configuration:

```
<Loggers>
    <!-- Custom Log Levels -->
    <CustomLevels>
        <Level name="A" intLevel="450" />
        <Level name="B" intLevel="460" />
    </CustomLevels>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <!-- Appender for Custom Level A -->
        <AppenderRef ref="AppenderForA" level="A" />
        <!-- Appender for Custom Level B -->
        <AppenderRef ref="AppenderForB" level="B" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Please assume: AppenderForA logging to A.log and AppenderForB logging to B.log.

I am creating Log instance as following:

```
    public class UserService1 {
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(UserService1.class);
    
        public void doSomething() {
            LOGGER.log(Level.forName("A", 450), "This is a log message with Custom Level A.");
      
  }
}
```

Since there are no specifically defined loggers for "UserService1", it will fallback to the RootLogger.
But I don't understand why the message "This is a log message with Custom Level" is being logged at the ConsoleAppender as well as B's Appender (i.e. B.log), even though I am providing the correct log level while logging the message.

I see the same problem while logging messages with B's level. They are being logged at the ConsoleAppender as well as at A's appender (i.e. A.log).

**One Observation:**
When I remove the B AppenderReference from the Root, messages logged with A's level only appear in A.log. I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue

Could you please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log4j2 configuration (Filters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76132925/log4j2-configuration-filters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your configuration:

- First of all, your configuration does not register custom levels correctly: the `<CustomLevels>` element must be a direct child of `<Configuration>` and there is no `<Level>` element:

  ```xml
  <Configuration>
    ...
    <CustomLevels>
      <CustomLevel name="A" intLevel="450"/>
      <CustomLevel name="B" intLevel="460"/>
    </CustomLevels>
    <Loggers>
    ...
    </Loggers>
  ```

  With your current config, if the configuration happens before any `Level.forName` call, a warning will be issued and your levels will be treated as `null`.
- Setting a `level` attribute on a logger config or appender reference works as a threshold filter: e.g. with `level="INFO"` no messages with a numerical level higher than 400 will be logged. If you want to filter out all messages with a level different from `A`, you must use a `<LevelMatchFilter>`:

  ```xml
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <!-- Appender for Custom Level A -->
      <AppenderRef ref="AppenderForA">
        <LevelMatchFilter level="A"/>
      </AppenderRef>
      <!-- Appender for Custom Level B -->
      <AppenderRef ref="AppenderForB"/>
        <LevelMatchFilter level="B"/>
      </AppenderRef>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
  ```

**Remark:** I have the impression that you are using levels to distinguish different aspects of your application. That is what [markers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Marker.html) are for:

> Markers are objects that are used to add easily filterable information to log messages. Markers can be hierarchical - each Marker may have a parent. This allows for broad categories being subdivided into more specific categories. An example might be a Marker named "Error" with children named "SystemError" and "ApplicationError".

With markers you use a `<MarkerFilter>`:

```xml
<AppenderRef ref="AppenderForA">
  <MarkerFilter marker="A"/>
</AppenderRef>
```