# Why does the ERROR level log appear in INFO log file? (How to separate log files based on LEVEL)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am new to logging so it seems that I have a bug in my log4j2 xml config. I want to have separate log files based on LEVEL. I means INFO level logs have to appear in info.log, ERROR level logs into error.log and so on.

However, with my current config, I see ERROR level logs in info.log file. How should I config log4j2 config file to separate logs into different files based on the LEVEL?

Here is my xml log4j2 config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" monitorInterval="10">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">/test/app_api</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<!--        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] [%-5level] [%c{1}] - %msg%n"/> -->
            <JsonTemplateLayout properties="true" eventTemplateUri="classpath:EventLayout.json" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="infologs"
                     fileName="${basePath}/info.log"
                     filePattern="${basePath}/info/%d{yyyy-MM}/info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip">
<!--        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] [%-5level] [%c{1}] - %msg%n"/> -->
            <JsonTemplateLayout properties="true" eventTemplateUri="classpath:EventLayout.json" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20">
                <Delete basePath="${basePath}" maxDepth="10">
                    <IfLastModified age="60d"/>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

       <RollingFile name="tracelogs"
                     fileName="${basePath}/trace.log"
                     filePattern="${basePath}/info/%d{yyyy-MM}/trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip">
<!--        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] [%-5level] [%c{1}] - %msg%n"/> -->
            <JsonTemplateLayout properties="true" eventTemplateUri="classpath:EventLayout.json" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20">
                <Delete basePath="${basePath}" maxDepth="10">
                    <IfLastModified age="60d"/>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
        
       <RollingFile name="debuglogs"
                     fileName="${basePath}/debug.log"
                     filePattern="${basePath}/info/%d{yyyy-MM}/debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip">
<!--        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] [%-5level] [%c{1}] - %msg%n"/> -->
            <JsonTemplateLayout properties="true" eventTemplateUri="classpath:EventLayout.json" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20">
                <Delete basePath="${basePath}" maxDepth="10">
                    <IfLastModified age="60d"/>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

       <RollingFile name="errorlogs"
                     fileName="${basePath}/error.log"
                     filePattern="${basePath}/info/%d{yyyy-MM}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip">
<!--        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] [%-5level] [%c{1}] - %msg%n"/>  -->
            <JsonTemplateLayout properties="true" eventTemplateUri="classpath:EventLayout.json" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20">
                <Delete basePath="${basePath}" maxDepth="10">
                    <IfLastModified age="60d"/>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" additivity="false"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="infologs" additivity="false"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="debuglogs"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="tracelogs"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="errorlogs"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: Please consider that your error logs will have no context in the error log file. This might make error analysis more difficult because you have to look in the info log file to see what happened at the time the error occured.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I did not understand what you mean by context in error log file. Would you please explain more what you mean and what should I do?

Comment: See also [Log4j2 Configuration (Filters)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76132925/11748454) for a solution that uses a routing appender.

Comment: @Hassan If you keep all the levels in one file you are going to have something like: 1) info - executed operation A; 2) info - executed operation B; 3) error - NullPointerException ... - Such info might help you to deduce that the NullPointerException will occur if operations A and B are executed in that sequence. Deducing this information from separate log files becomes much harder, especially for a system under load.